# Open Modal displaying info about clicked target in React

Tags: reactjs, simplemodal

I created a list of icons from a JSON object, displaying an image and a name value. I want to make them clickable so that a modal opens, displaying more of that particular icon's details. I see there are number of external libraries that could be used to generate a Modal but it seems like overkill.

Is there a simple solution for creating a Modal-component that doesn't involve using a third party library?

Comment: React 16 introduced a concept called [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) that can implement modals in a pretty straightforward way. Most third-party libraries likely use portals as well.

Comment: While you could do it yourself, modal are fairly complex-- you need logic to handle clicking outside the modal, showing/closing the modal, and quality of life stuff like dimming the background and adding transitions. Unless you really need to limit build size I'd recommend a third part library. MUI Dialogs have worked well for me: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/

Answer (score 0):

> You can use React createPortal() for overlays.
>
> [To visit the full code of overlay you can checkout my sandbox where I created the basic overlay](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-haslett-uup2p7?file=/src/App.js)

Create Portal takes two parameters, first one is the Child component that we want to use and the second one is where do we want to put that child component.
ex- **React.createPortal(, doucment.getElementById("overlay")**

It is important to you make sure the parent component is created
**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
   <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
   <meta
    name="description"
    content="Web site created using create-react-app"
 />
 <title>react</title>
</head>
 <body class="bg-white">
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
   <div id="root"></div>
   <div id="overlay"></div>   
 </body>
</html>
```

**React component**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [isOverlayOpen, setIsOverlayOpen] = useState(false);
return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
     <button onClick={() => setIsOverlayOpen(true)}>
    <span role="img" aria-label="icons">
      
    </span>
  </button>
   {isOverlayOpen &&
    createPortal(
      <div
        className="overlay"
        onClick={() => {
          setIsOverlayOpen(false);
         //for remove overlay i used to onClick also on it you 
         can 
         create a separate button
        }}
      >
        hello
      </div>,
      document.getElementById("overlay")
    )}
</div>
```

);
}

**Styles.css**

```
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
 position: relative;
 } 
.App {
font-family: sans-serif;
text-align: center;
 }
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100%;
   background-color: black;
 opacity: 0.7;
   top: 0;
}
```